# Prestashop doesn't show backoffice product page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

When I try to open my backoffice product page, it shows just blank white page.

There is no problem with front office.

When I enable debug mode, it shows this message when I try to open front office

[image]

and shows no products in back office, but not blank page.

Please help me. I use prestashop 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Added the following code on line `43` of `prestashop_folder/config/smartyfront.config.inc.php`

```
if (!isset($params['s'])) $params['s'] = '';
```

Information get from [there](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/449449-notice-undefined-index-s-in-configsmartyfrontco/)